# Add ID/class to objects from createElement method

Tags: html, css

This [w3schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp) mentions the HTML DOM createElement() Method. For example, you can create a button by

> var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");

However, how can I add ID/class to this button? And what else can I do with it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One way with Javascript, is by using setAttribute:

```
element.setAttribute(name, value);
```

Example:

```
var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.setAttribute("id", "btn_id");
btn.setAttribute("class", "btn_class");
btn.setAttribute("width", "250px");
btn.setAttribute("data-comma-delimited-array", "one,two,three,four");
btn.setAttribute("anything-random", document.getElementsByTagName("img").length);
```

The advantage of this way is that you can assign arbitrary values to arbitrary names.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute

Answer (score 11):

You could assign to its property:

```
var btn=document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.id = 'btn_id';
btn.className = 'btn_class';
```